# Encryption and decryption method with elliptic curve public key pairs

Tags: java, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I'm not a cryptography expert, and while I have experience applying encryption with a standard RSA public key, I've never tried encrypting with an elliptic curve public key. If there's a developer familiar with applying elliptic curve public keys, I'd like to ask for answers to the following questions:
The encryption and decryption with the code provided work well, but I want to confirm if the method applied in the question is correct.

```
    import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
    import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
    import java.security.Security;
    import java.security.spec.ECGenParameterSpec;
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import java.util.Base64;
    
    fun main() {
    
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    
    // 1. Key pair generation
    val spec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1");
    val keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
    keyPairGen.initialize(spec);
    val keyPair = keyPairGen.generateKeyPair();
    
    val publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
    val privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
    
    // 2. Generation of crand (32 bytes)
    val crand = "12345678901234567890123456789012";
    val crandBytes = crand.getBytes();
    
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("ECIES");
    
    /* 
        3. Encryption
        Question: Is setting ENCRYPT_MODE and applying the publicKey the same expression as applying Encrypt(crandBytes, publicKey) in RSA?
        Question:To apply encryption with an elliptic curve key pair, is it correct to use ECIES like below?
    */
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    val cryptoWcranddData = cipher.doFinal(crandBytes);
    
    val encryptedDataStr = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cryptoWcranddData);
    System.out.println("Encrypted Data (Base64 Encoded): " + encryptedDataStr);
        
    // Decryption
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    val decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedDataStr));
    val decryptedDataStr = new String(decryptedData);
    
    System.out.println
    "Decrypted Data: " + decryptedDataStr);
    }
```